# NPM installation errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to create a new project and wanted to install NPM in the directory of my project, but it showed these errors. I currently have the latest versions of both NPM and Node.js.

```
Naomis-Air:~ naomivictoriaobame$ npm -v
7.24.0
Naomis-Air:~ naomivictoriaobame$ npm install npm@latest -g
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/naomivictoriaobame/.npm/_logs/2021-10-16T20_55_50_627Z-debug.log
Naomis-Air:~ naomivictoriaobame$  npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
Naomis-Air:~ naomivictoriaobame$
```

Comment: [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though the current user needs permission to make change to the npm directory. You can run the following command to give the current user access modify that directory:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Comment: The package directory in the question is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`. Please don't recommend to change the owner or permissions of this folder or to install a global package with `sudo`.

Comment: @jabaa I'd agree with not changing the permissions, but how else would you `install -g`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) Installing `npm` with `sudo` and `-g` would overwrite an installation that's managed by a system package manager. That could break the package and a system upgrade could also break something.

Comment: @jabaa As if a package manager would care.... and the sky will fall on your head. To me this is bent logic alike pretending that one could use the package manager without `sudo`. Maybe cut down on the assumption and stick to the facts? And the fact is, that you've provided no valid answer at all.

Comment: @MartinZeitler That's the place the system package manager has installed NPM. If OP manually overwrites this installation and updates the system, the package manager will overwrite OP's installation. OP would have to manually upgrade NPM every time the system package manager upgrades NPM. It should be obvious that this is a bad idea. My answer is to follow the NPM documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I reinstalled npm with a node version manager instead and those errors are no longer showing ! @jabaa